Ошибка получения данных: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
Страница информации о товаре, выводящаяся из бд. В другом проекте все прекрасно работало, в этом показывает ошибку. И то что id=%s

Ошибка получения данных: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the
right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1

<?php
    session_start();
    include "connect.php";
    
    $role = (isset($_SESSION["role"])) ? $_SESSION["role"] : "guest";
    $id = (isset($_GET['id'])) ? $_GET['id'] : 0;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `count` > 0 AND `product_id`=". $id;
    if(!$result = $connect->query($sql))
        return die ("Ошибка получения данных: ". $connect->error);

    if(!$product = $result->fetch_assoc())
        return header("Location:index.php?message=Товар отсутствует");

    include "header.php";
?>


прочтите как правильно работать с базой данных из РНР и перепишите код.
